# Ignore spaces in Rails uniqueness check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

How can I ignore spaces when checking to see if a string is unique? For instance, if my model just stores a string and an entry is "Hello World", "HelloWorld" should be flagged as being non-unique. Is there a way I can attach this clause to the `validates: uniqueness: ...` validator, or do I need to write my own method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to write your own method:

```
before_save :check_name_uniqueness

def check_name_uniqueness
  name = self.name.presence
  if name
    name = name.downcase.gsub(" ", "").strip.squish
    if self.class.exists?(name: name)
      self.errors.add(:base, "already existing name")
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  else
    self.errors.add(:name, "cant be blank")
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I've just tried to implement it but it's allowing me save two names that are the same bar the first letter being capitalised i.e. `Hello world` and `hello world`. Is there a quick way to check against the database records for uniqueness ignoring spaces and capitals? Or is @T J's answer below the best solution?

Comment: You can add a where clause : `if self.class.where("LOWER(name) = ?", name).exists?` or with PostgreSQL `if self.class.where('name ILIKE ?', name)`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that later

Comment: Sorry for being a pest but I'm still having trouble when an entry in the database is `Hello World` and a user tries to create `Helloworld` i.e. they don't get flagged as similar. Is it possible to query the database ignoring spaces in the values already stored or am I asking too much?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try adding an additional column to use as a unique column and set up your validation like:

```
before_validation :set_unique_name
validates :unique_name, :uniqueness => {:message => "name is already taken"}

def set_unique_name
  self.unique_name = self.name.downcase.gsub(" ", "").strip
end
```